Is Labview/Multifunction DAQ supported on an M2/M3 based Macbook
When trying to install the driver for my cDAQ-9189 (Which I assume is the NI-DAQmx_Base_15.0.0) the installer reports "This package is incompatible with this version of macOS".
So what are my options to running the DAQ from my M2 Macbook?
I've also tried running on Windows 11 through Parallels Desktop, but the device isn't recognized.

"So what are my options to running the DAQ from my M2 Macbook?" Um, use a version of macOS that is supported? I'm not sure this is something we can help with. Vendors provide support for whatever versions they choose.

NI only lists MacOS as supported they don't define if any chipset is, or isn't, supported. I was hoping someone had encountered this and received some notification from NI one way or another.

Looks like they list specific versions to me: https://www.ni.com/en/support/documentation/compatibility/18/labview-and-macos-compatibility.html

The closest to my setup is: macOS 13 (x86_64) Ventura.... of course this isn't an M2 chipset, M2 is clearly not on the list therefor not supported.

The cDAQ-9189 is supported by the latest DAQmx software. Theoretically, if your machine and OS are supported, it should work.
DAQ support table
